# Update object in Firebase Cloud firestore use Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I be working with firebase and angular 4 in this new thing is firestore,  I try update one of the documents but I have this error.

[image]

And this is my componet

[image]

If I remove the interfaces I mean if I do this, noteDoc: **AngularFirestoreDocument;** instead of **noteDoc:AngularFirestoreDocument;**
the error go but I prefer use the interface Some one can help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try providing values to all non-nullable properties:

```
this.noteDoc.update({
  content: this.newData,
  hearts: this.noteDoc.hearts
}
```

or make hearts nullable as per id.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might actually be a bug with AngularFire, I make a temporaly solution modify the interfaces like this

```
interface User {
 name?: String;
 email?: String;
 id?: any;
}
```

I hope this help some one thanks